# How to get contact form 7 field value in mail?

Tags: php, contact-form

This is the form I created on contact form 7. On the mail option I get an option to choose which field values I want to receive on email. I used drop down list tag and pipe to do the drop down thing and pick the amount but every time it picks the display value. So for now how I can send the data of selected Amount field to the mail. Do I need to create a custom tag ?

```
<label> Mobile Number </label>
[tel* tel-385 id:mobile]
<label> Amount </label>
<select name="Amount"  id="amount" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="30">30 pesos $1.00</option>
<option value="100">100 pesos $2.70</option>
<option value="200">200 pesos $5.20</option>
<option value="300">300 pesos $7.60</option>
</select>
[paypalsubmit email:###### itemamount:amount "SEND LOAD"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is quite simple .just create the drop down list using the tag ..and than copy the complete  html drop down code .Directly put the on contact form 7 .